# It's possible define bean stereotypes via XML?

Tags: xml, spring, stereotype

It's possible, via XML, define a bean stereotype? Something as:

```
<bean ... stereotype="org.springframework.stereotype.Service">
</bean>
```

or,

```
<bean...>
    <stereotype class="mypackage.myStereotype" />
</bean>
```

?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2964180/adding-an-annotation-to-a-runtime-generated-method-class-using-javassist

Comment: Hi, Andrei. I'm trying use the default behaviour provided by spring stereotypes into a project that must use xml configuration. I would like, too, define my custom stereotypes and use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest solution would be to use arbitrary spring bean metadata as follows:

```
<bean id="fooService" class="org.example.FooServiceImpl">
    <meta key="stereotype" value="mypackage.myStereotype" />
</bean>
```

The definition of the meta element in [spring-beans.xsd](http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd) is:

```
<xsd:element name="meta" type="metaType">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation><![CDATA[
Arbitrary metadata attached to a bean definition.
        ]]></xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
</xsd:element>

<xsd:complexType name="metaType">
    <xsd:attribute name="key" type="xsd:string" use="required">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation><![CDATA[
The key name of the metadata attribute being defined.
            ]]></xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
    </xsd:attribute>
    <xsd:attribute name="value" type="xsd:string" use="required">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation><![CDATA[
The value of the metadata attribute being defined (as a simple String).
            ]]></xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
    </xsd:attribute>
</xsd:complexType>
```

You can then use [`BeanDefinitionRegistry.getBeanDefinition(String)`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/BeanDefinitionRegistry.html) and [`BeanDefinition.getAttribute(String name)`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/AttributeAccessor.html#getAttribute-java.lang.String-) to read the stereotype of the bean and process it.

Another possibility would be using the spring bean [schema authoring facilities](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#xml-custom). Therefore you would need to implement a [`BeanDefinitionDecorator`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/BeanDefinitionDecorator.html) as described in the [reference documentation example](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#extensible-xml-custom-just-attributes).

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to dynamically add annotations to your classes. Simple answer to your question is: **No, it is not possible to apply stereotype annotation via XML.**

However stereotype annotation usually serve only as a marking annotations for AOP components (and *component scan*). You can define your own [AOP behavior](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html). Of course you won't be able to use any built in `<xyz:annotation-driven \>` shortcut declaration / configuration.

Comment: Thanks Pavel, it's possible define stereotypes and use them without annotations? Can i mark that a class or a bean is stereotyped via xml? Maybe <meta /> tag inside a bean definition?

Comment: @Helder What will be the use-case of that? Maybe I can provide you with alternative approach.

Comment: Pavel, sorry for not answering you before and for my English. 

We are developing a security framework based on XACML (https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/tc_home.php?wg_abbrev=xacml#XACML20) and we defined a service oriented layer structure based on service models that exists in core of our solution. We designed a stereotype to each service model and the framework clients (basically others products/projects in our organization) can use them to extends or replace service behaviours.

Comment: A common behaviour of service models is translate exceptions to a known exception by service clients. We doesn't can use specific spring annotations directly on core implementation (core-impl) because we provide support to others DI technologies (an other jar will binding the core-impl with the technology: spring, cdi, etc.), thus, we preferred use xml. Therefore, we need some way to declare a stereotype to beans or types/classes via xml. We also do not desire coupling the aspect for implement behaviors to a specific package or type, except the stereotype.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Adding stereotype manually to a set of beans is in my view equivalent to defining list of beans. So why not just do that?